# Comments/Review sections text doesn't set div size in WooCommerce Theme

Tags: html, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm playing around with a WP theme and WooCommerce. I have a basic product added, however the reviews/comments on the products don't seem to display any text. If you take a look at the screenshot below you'll see that there is a box/div created for the comment, however the text inside of this is not visible.

Does anyone have any ideas what could be causing this?

http://spencerdavieson.com/product/embers-destines-1/ <---- That's the link to the specific page with the issue

Thanks in advance!

[image: red outline shows the section with the issue]

Comment: Are there any reviews?

Answer (score 0):

Yea i did a test one to see. If you right click the box area on the page and do inspect eliment you can see a review from a user called marc